# Run stored procedure in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have procedure with params:

```
procedure GetReceipt(iPaymentID    in number
                    ,oReceipt      out sys_refcursor
                    ,oReceiptItems out sys_refcursor);
```

I try to run this my anonymous block:

```
SET serveroutput on;  
DECLARE                                    
  oReceipt sys_refcursor;
  oReceiptItems sys_refcursor;  
BEGIN
  API.MOD.GetReceipt(4209735, oReceipt, oReceiptItems);
  dbms_output.put_line('oReceipt: ' || oReceipt);
  dbms_output.put_line('oReceiptItems: ' || oReceiptItems);
END;
```

I get this error:

```
Error report:
ORA-06550: Строка 6, столбец 24:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||'
ORA-06550: Строка 6, столбец 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: Строка 7, столбец 24:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||'
ORA-06550: Строка 7, столбец 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

How call this procedure? Where my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bind variables to store the cursors and [`PRINT`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve031.htm#SQPUG051) to print them:

```
VARIABLE receipt REFCURSOR;
VARIABLE receiptitems REFCURSOR;

BEGIN
  API.MOD.GetReceipt(4209735, :receipt, :receiptitems);
END;
/

PRINT receipt;
PRINT receiptitems;
```

> Where my mistake?

A [cursor](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/explicit_cursor.htm#LNPLS01313) is a named pointer to a private SQL area that stores information for processing a specific query. It does not make sense to concatenate a pointer to something internal to the database with a string.

If you want to display the values in your PL/SQL block then you will need to loop through each record of the cursor and get the individual column values for that record and then use `DBMS_OUTPUT` to display them:

```
SET serveroutput on;  
DECLARE                                    
  oReceipt      sys_refcursor;
  oReceiptItems sys_refcursor;  

  col1 RECEIPT_TABLE.COL1%TYPE;     -- Same data type as COL1 of the RECEIPT_TABLE table
  col2 RECEIPT_TABLE.COL2%TYPE;     -- Same data type as COL2 of the RECEIPT_TABLE table
  col3 RECEIPT_TABLE.COL3%TYPE;     -- Same data type as COL3 of the RECEIPT_TABLE table

  rec  RECEIPT_ITEMS_TABLE%ROWTYPE; -- Assumes the cursor is returning all the columns from
                                    -- the RECEIPT_ITEMS_TABLE table
BEGIN
  API.MOD.GetReceipt(4209735, oReceipt, oReceiptItems);

  dbms_output.put_line('oReceipt:');
  LOOP
    FETCH oReceipt INTO col1, col2, col3; -- Store the values from the current record
    EXIT WHEN oReceipt%NOTFOUND;          -- Stop if the end of the cursor has been reached
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( col1 || ' ' || col2 || ' ' || col3 );
                                          -- Output the values
  END LOOP;

  dbms_output.put_line('oReceiptItems:');
  LOOP
    FETCH oReceiptItems INTO rec;         -- Fetch the current row into a record
    EXIT WHEN oReceipt%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( rec.colA || ' ' || rec.colB || ' ' || rec.colC );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

`sys_refcursor` returns `record set`, may not be just a column.

So, you can not message it as a classical string with `dbms_output.put_line`. There should exists some columns(sub-components) of this argument in your routine like `oReceiptItems.col_a` or `oReceiptItems.col_b` so that you could message by these columns as strings with `dbms_output.put_line`.

Comment: A [cursor](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/explicit_cursor.htm#LNPLS01313) is a named pointer to a private SQL area that stores information for processing a specific query - it is not a [rowtype](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/rowtype_attribute.htm#LNPLS01342).